# Runtime compiling a function with arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x, codegen

I am trying to use [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile%22compile%22) to runtime generate a Python function accepting arguments as follows.

```
import types
import ast

code = compile("def add(a, b): return a + b", '<string>', 'exec')
fn = types.FunctionType(code, {}, name="add")
print(fn(4, 2))
```

But it fails with

`TypeError: <module>() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Is there anyway to compile a function accepting arguments using this way or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Can't you just do `exec(code)` and then `add(4, 2)`?

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I am curious why above fails or if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: `fn` is not the `add()` function.  It is a function that will, upon execution, define an `add()` function in its namespace (which you didn't save a reference to, so there's no way to actually invoke `add()`).

Comment: @ForceBru you can do that, but that's generally not the way that you should generate your code.

Comment: @jasonharper Would that mean `globals()['add'] = fn` followed by `add(2, 4)` should work? (it doesn't so I take it I understood it wrong).

Comment: `fn` isn't using the normal globals, you explicitly passed a globals dict when you constructed the function.  If you'd saved a reference to that dict, you should find `add` within it after calling `fn()`.

Comment: I tried `types.FunctionType(code, globals(), name="add")` followed by `add(2, 4)`. Got a name not defined error. Is it not possible to modify the global namespace this way?

Comment: You might want to compile a lambda, then call the function which will return the lambda, which you can then call with parameters.  The anonymity of the function dodges the namespace issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile returns the code object to create a module. In Python 3.6, if you were to disassemble your code object:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(fn)
 0 LOAD_CONST    0 (<code object add at ...., file "<string>" ...>)
 2 LOAD_CONST    1 ('add')
 4 MAKE_FUNCTION 0
 6 STORE_NAME    0 (add)
 8 LOAD_CONST    2 (None)
10 RETURN_VALUE
```

That literally translates to `make function; name it 'add'; return None`.

This code means that your function runs the creation of the module, not returning a module or function itself. So essentially, what you're actually doing is equivalent to the following:

```
def f():
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

print(f(4, 2))
```

For the question of how do you work around, the answer is it depends on what you want to do. For instance, if you want to compile a function using `compile`, the simple answer is you won't be able to without doing something similar to the following.

```
# 'code' is the result of the call to compile.
# In this case we know it is the first constant (from dis),
# so we will go and extract it's value
f_code = code.co_consts[0]
add = FunctionType(f_code, {}, "add")

>>> add(4, 2)
6
```

Since defining a function in Python requires running Python code (there is no static compilation by default other than compiling to bytecode), you can pass in custom `globals` and `locals` dictionaries, and then extract the values from those.

```
glob, loc = {}, {}
exec(code, glob, loc)

>>> loc['add'](4, 2)
6
```

But the real answer is if you want to do this, the simplest way is generally to generate [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) using the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), and compiling that into module code and evaluating or executing the module.

If you want to do bytecode transformation, I'd suggest looking at the [codetransformer](http://codetransformer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package on PyPi.

**TL;DR** using `compile` will only ever return code for a module, and most serious code generation is done either with ASTs or by manipulating byte codes.

Comment: Interesting. How to get a reference to the code object and make it callable in this case? (Making a self note to use dis in future..)

Comment: @budchanchao I've updated my answer to cover more detail

Comment: Reading the line *add = FunctionType(code, {}, "add")* I thought of replacing *code* with *f_code* -- it worked, so I guess is should be.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other way to do that?

For what's worth: I recently created a `@compile_fun` goodie that considerably eases the process of applying `compile` on a function. It relies on `compile` so nothing different than was explained by the above answers, but it provides an easier way to do it. Your example writes:

```
@compile_fun
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

assert add(1, 2) == 3
```

You can see that you now can't debug into `add` with your IDE. Note that this does not improve runtime performance, nor protects your code from reverse-engineering, but it might be convenient if you do not want your users to see the internals of your function when they debug. Note that the obvious drawback is that they will not be able to help you debug your lib, so use with care!

See `makefun`[documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/#compile_fun) for details.

Comment: Yeah, but this decorator does the fancy version of nothing, right?

Comment: Your comment is not very clear ;) - if your question is "what does it do", the post above explains it quite well I guess. Now if by "nothing" you mean "no acceleration nor real obfuscation", yes you are right. That's what `compile` does, and so does this decorator ;)

Comment: You are compiling a function that is already compiled, right.  Before it can call the decorator, the body has already been parsed and compiled.  If you called it on the string or something, it would have an actual use.  But as it is, it spends time and accomplishes nothing that has not already been done.  I don't see how that is unclear.

Comment: Thanks @JayObermark, this is now clearer :) .Indeed,`compile` is a "false friend" as we could think that it compiles (C-like, as in Cython compilation) python code and therefore can accelerate it. But it doesnt, it is just useful to create code dynamically from string.I fell into this trap myself some time ago,and lost time just experimenting in order to find the truth.Thanks to this decorator I am now able to prove myself easily that it does not bring any speed :) Still it removes the src from IDE debugging stack which may be convenient in rare edge cases. Thanks for clarifying your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I think this accomplishes what you want in a better way

```
import types

text = "lambda (a, b): return a + b"
code = compile(text, '<string>', 'eval')
body = types.FunctionType(code, {})
fn = body()

print(fn(4, 2))
```

The function being anonymous resolves the implicit namespace issues.
And returning it as a value by using the mode *'eval'* is cleaner that lifting it out of the code contents, since it does not rely upon the specific habits of the compiler.

More usefully, as you seem to have noticed but not gotten to using yet, since you import `ast`, the `text` passsed to `compile` can actually be an `ast` object, so you can use ast transformation on it.

```
import types
import ast
from somewhere import TransformTree

text = "lambda (a, b): return a + b"
tree = ast.parse(text)
tree = TransformTree().visit(tree)
code = compile(text, '<string>', 'eval')
body = types.FunctionType(code, {})
fn = body()

print(fn(4, 2))
```